# Angular ng-if for checking empty string not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my view, I have the below code to display some data from angular scope variables. The first two lines work fine. They display data from the scope variables but the line from `ng-if` does not display. What is wrong with my `ng-if` condition?

```
<div ng-controller="PaymentCtrl">

    <h3>Payment successfully posted {{PaymentID}}</h3>

    <h3> Receipt number {{ReceiptNumber}} </h3>

    <div ng-if="{{ReceiptNumber}}">
        <h3>Receipt generated with receipt number {{ReceiptNumber}}</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `{{`/`}}`, `ng-if` takes an expression, not an interpolated value.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos You should submit that as the answer perhaps with a slightly more descriptive explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) takes an expression.

> `<ANY ng-if="expression"> ... <ANY>`

See the [AngularJS expression docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) for more information on what this entails exactly. In your example, you are instead supplying an [interpolated value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate). Try the following...

```
<div ng-if="ReceiptNumber">
    <h3>Receipt generated with receipt number {{ReceiptNumber}}</h3>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zrxpLbr1/1/) - demo comparing both wrong and correct appreach